# How to apply random forest to predict bug in a given commit?

Tags: python, random-forest

I have dataset that contains information on commits (commit data, number of lines,
if the commit introduce or not a bug repect to the previous one, and so on).

I need to run Random Forest to classify the column "Bug" which can assume three values: "Increase", "Decrease" or "Stable".

For each commit I need to consider as a train set all commits that in temporal order precede the commit I am considering.

At the end I need to have an overview of how the model behaves.

I wrote the following code:

```
def load_dataset(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    df['commit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['commit_date'])
    df.sort_values(by='commit_date', inplace=True)
    return df

def get_subset_dataframe_from_commit_data_to_init(df, commit_date):
    return df[df['commit_date'] < commit_date]


def train_and_evaluate_rf_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier()
    rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
    return accuracy, f1, roc_auc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = load_dataset("dataset.csv")
    df = preprocess_data(df)
    accuracy_metrics = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        commit_date = row['commit_date']
        X = get_subset_dataframe_from_commit_data_to_init(df, commit_date)
        y = df.iloc[index]['Bug']
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
        rf_pipe = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),
                            ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, min_samples_split=5))])
        rf_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
        accuracy, f1, roc_auc = train_and_evaluate_rf_model(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)

        accuracy_metrics.append({'Commit_Date': commit_date,
                                 'Accuracy': accuracy,
                                 'F1-Score': f1,
                                 'ROC-AUC': roc_auc})

    metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(accuracy_metrics)
    print("\nReport:")
    print(metrics_df)
```

Unfortunaly, I always receive this exception(that refer to line rf_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)):

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [0, 6]
```

I suppose that the fuction 'train_test_split' is not called in a correctly becuase I need to use as train set the sebuset of commits that precede in temporal order the current commit.

The initial dataset is unballanced, indeed contains only a few instancies of "Increase" "Decrease" (more o less 95% are "Stable" and the remainig ones are "Increase"/"Decrease).

Comment: Please provide us with a *minimal reproducible example* with a *sample dataset* for debugging. Why you fit\train your model `rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)`  within function and then use fit\train your pipeline including model again  `rf_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)`. Can you reason it ? Either use model or pipeline